# Translating english node to spanish

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

How to create a Spanish version of node which is in English and that Spanish version of node should contain all fields from English content except one field. That one field should translate to Spanish Lang

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding Spanish language in your site Regional settings (with Locale module from Drupal core) you need to install the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module.

Internationalization module comes with a lot of submodules. Read about them in the documentation: [Submodules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279136) and see if some of them are useful to your multilingual setup.

The [Synchronize translations](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279460) submodule is the one you want where you can set that some fields are the same for all languages.

Comment: Thanks for giving me information. It's really helpful. But I need to save a node programmatically. I am having thousands of nodes already which are already created in English language. I want to save/create each node in Spanish version with English content.

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about that in your question. You should probably create a new question with all the information about your problem. I'm guessing you'll be able to use the Rules module for that.